# Airflow parameters to Postgres Operator

Tags: amazon-redshift, airflow

I am trying to pass the execution date as runtime parameter to the postgres operator

```
class MyPostgresOperator(PostgresOperator):
    template_fields = ('sql','parameters')

task = MyPostgresOperator(
  task_id='test_date',
  postgres_conn_id='redshift',
  sql="test_file.sql",
  parameters={'crunch_date':'{{ ds }}'},
  dag=dag
)
```

Then I try to use this parameter in the sql query to accept the value as passed by the dag

```
select 
{{ crunch_date }} as test1,
```

The dag sends the parameter correctly, however the query is just taking a null value instead of the execution date that is passed. Is there a way to have the postgresql with redshift accept the correct value for this parameter?

Comment: Its redshift @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Remove the spaces around `{{ds}}`

Comment: @psychoCoder I have tried that, but it doesn't work. While the dag is sending the parameters correctly, I have only issue with the sql file not recognising the parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to update your sql query as below:

```sql
select 
{{ ds }} as test1,
```

You won't be able to use one templated field in other. If you want to pass a param in task and use it in Jinja template, use `params` parameter.

**UPDATE**:

But do note that `params` is not a templated field. And if you template it, it won't render as nested templating won't work.

```py
task = MyPostgresOperator(
  task_id='test_date',
  postgres_conn_id='redshift',
  sql="test_file.sql",
  params={'textstring':'abc'},
  dag=dag
)
```

where `test_file.sql` is:

```sql
select 
{{ params.textstring }} as test1,
```

Check 4th point in https://medium.com/datareply/airflow-lesser-known-tips-tricks-and-best-practises-cf4d4a90f8f to understand more about `params`.

Comment: I am not sure if you have understood my problem there. The solution you have given is already something I have tried but failed. I will give another simple example:

task = MyPostgresOperator(
  task_id='test_date',
  postgres_conn_id='redshift',
  sql="test_file.sql",
  parameters={'textstring':'abc'},
  dag=dag
)
Here textstring is the parameter name and abc is its value
Now I want to get the parameter value in the sql file:
select 
{{ textstring }} as test1
But the textstring is just null

Comment: Thanks a ton, you're a saviour. That works exactly as intended.

Comment: One issue here, the solution works perfectly when passing a string value but does not work with the Airflow ds parameter
    
    sql='ETL models/test_file.sql',
    params={'crunchdate':'{{ ds }}'},

In the test file:
    '{{ params.crunchdate }}' as test1

It gives an error:
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "{{ ds }}"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the airflow macros inside the query string - which needs to be passed to the redshift.

Example:

```
PostgresOperator(task_id="run_on_redshift",
                 dag=dag,
                 postgres_conn_id=REDSHIFT_CONN_ID,
                 sql="""
                        UNLOAD ('select * from abc.xyz') TO 's3://path/{{ds}}/' iam_role 's3_iam_role' DELIMITER AS '^' ALLOWOVERWRITE addquotes ESCAPE HEADER parallel off;
                     """
                 )
```

Comment: I understand I can use macro inside the sql query. But what I would like to do is not write the entire SQL query inside the dag but have only the sql file called inside the dag and then pass a parameter from the dag to this sql file